# Improve query performance in large collection with large documents using indexes or in any other possible way

Tags: python, database, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I am using PyMongo with Flask and I would like to know how to optimize a query, as I am filtering within a large collection (8793 documents) with large documents.

This is one of the document structures of the collections:

[image]

As you can see, it has 4 properties (simulationID, simulationPartID, timePass and status, which stores many arrays). This collection has a size of 824.4MB. The average size of the documents is 96.0KB.

[image]

Basically, I’m trying to find the documents that have simulationPartID **7** (1256 documents) and filter on them the array index equal to the **nodeID** value (which I receive as a parameter) within the **status** property, and take the fourth or fifth element of this array (depending on the **case** parameter), in addition to append the timePass.

```
def node_history(nodeID, case):
    coordinates = []
    node_data = db['node_data']
    db.node_data.create_index([('simulationPartID', 1), ('simulationID', 1)])
    if case == 'Temperature':
        for document in node_data.find({"simulationPartID": 7}):
            coordinates.append([document['timePass'], document['status'][int(nodeID)-1][3]])
    elif case == 'Stress':
        for document in node_data.find({"simulationPartID": 7}):
            coordinates.append([document['timePass'], document['status'][int(nodeID)-1][4]])
    else:
        pass
    coordinates.sort()
    return json.dumps(coordinates, default=json_util.default)
```

As I mentioned, the collection is very large, and the query takes about 30 - 60 seconds to be performed, depending on the machine, but I want it to run as quickly as possible because I want my application to be as interactive as possible. As you can seeI already tried to create a index in both **simulationID** and **simulationPartID** properties.

I never worked with large collections before, so I'm not into indexing. I don't even know if I did it properly in my code. So, I would like to know if there is a way to optimize my query using a different approach of indexes, or in any other possible way, and make it faster.

Data samples:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f83f54d45104462898aba67"
  },
  "simulationID": "001",
  "simulationPartID": 7,
  "timePass": 0,
  "status": [
    [
      1,
      1.34022987724954e-40,
      0.00220799725502729,
      20,
      114.911392211914
    ],
    [
      2,
      0.00217749993316829,
      0.00220799725502729,
      20,
      -2.0458550453186
    ],
    [
      3,
      0.0020274999551475,
      0.00235799723304808,
      20,
      -1.33439755439758
    ],
    [
      4,
      3.36311631437956e-44,
      0.00235799723304808,
      20,
      148.233413696289
    ],
    [
      5,
      1.02169119449431e-38,
      0.000149997213156894,
      20,
      -25633.59765625
    ],
  ]
},

{  
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f83f54d45104462898aba68"
  },
  "simulationID": "001",
  "simulationPartID": 7,
  "timePass": 1,
  "status": [
    [
      1,
      1.34022987724954e-40,
      0.00220799725502729,
      20,
      114.911392211914
    ],
    [
      2,
      0.00217749993316829,
      0.00220799725502729,
      20,
      -2.0458550453186
    ],
    [
      3,
      0.0020274999551475,
      0.00235799723304808,
      20,
      -1.33439755439758
    ],
    [
      4,
      3.36311631437956e-44,
      0.00235799723304808,
      20,
      148.233413696289
    ],
    [
      5,
      1.02169119449431e-38,
      0.000149997213156894,
      20,
      -25633.59765625
    ],
  ]
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5f83f54d45104462898aba69"
  },
  "simulationID": "001",
  "simulationPartID": 7,
  "timePass": 2,
  "status": [
    [
      1,
      1.34022987724954e-40,
      0.00220799725502729,
      20,
      114.911392211914
    ],
    [
      2,
      0.00217749993316829,
      0.00220799725502729,
      20,
      -2.0458550453186
    ],
    [
      3,
      0.0020274999551475,
      0.00235799723304808,
      20,
      -1.33439755439758
    ],
    [
      4,
      3.36311631437956e-44,
      0.00235799723304808,
      20,
      148.233413696289
    ],
    [
      5,
      1.02169119449431e-38,
      0.000149997213156894,
      20,
      -25633.59765625
    ],
  ]
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample documents as text, not as screenshot. I refuse to copy sample data from an image.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I edited the post with the samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you create the index for **each** query? An index is created only once when you deploy the application.

Your `find` returns the full document, which is not needed. You can limit the result with [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)

```
db.node_data.find({"simulationPartID": 7}, {"timePass": 1, "status": { '$slice': [ 3, 1 ] } } )
```

This should return the data much faster because it returns **only** the values you like to get.

If you like to select a sub-elements from array, then you can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { timePass: 2 } },
  { $set: { status: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$status", 4 ] } } },
  { $set: { status: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$status", 3 ] } } },
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rVvrF3ngMOn)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Yes, the index is created only once, like you said.
I have this as a result of your query:

`{ "timePass" : 0, "status" : [ [ 4, 3.36311631437956e-44, 0.00235799723304808, 20, 148.233413696289 ] ] }`

etc...

What if I would like to return just the fourth element of the status array and not the whole array? 

I would like to have something like this: 

`{ "timePass" : 0, "status" : [ [ 20] ] }`

@Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: Then you have to use an aggregation pipeline. With simple `find` you cannot filter an element from an array which is an element of an array. Maybe I will have a look later this evening.

Comment: Just another question: how can I use this aggregate query to find all the data correspondent to simulationPartID 7 and not just the data correspondent to the timePass value I set (in your example you set 2 as value)?